# Renew \title command to include an image right before the text

Tags: graphics, titles

I am writing a series of company internal documents and decided to use latex and a custom .sty file so that I can have only content in the actual .tex document and have a consistent style for all documents.

I would like to add the company logo right before the title of the document. So I'm thinking of putting a `\renewcommand` in the *.sty document, but I cannot have a `\includegraphics` there since it's outside the main document flow.

How would I go about this? The examples of possible solutions I've seen involved using `\begin{titlepage}` etc that will create a whole separate page that I do not want and then I'm unable to define a custom title for each document.

What I have so far in terms of how I would like to have my title structured is:

document1.tex:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{company_style}

%opening
\title{01 - The First Document}


\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

and company_style.sty:

```
\ProvidesPackage{company_style}

\title{Comany XYZ \\ {\LARGE \@specificTitle} }
\renewcommand*{\title}[1]{\def\@specificTitle{#1}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can include the company logo as part of the title in your style file. Here's an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{company_style.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{company_style}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}

\let\oldtitle\title
\renewcommand{\title}[1]{\oldtitle{%
  Company XYZ \\[\bigskipamount]
  \includegraphics[height=5\baselineskip]{example-image} \\[\bigskipamount]
  #1}}

\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{company_style}

\title{01 - The First Document}
\author{A.N.\ Author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

This is some content
\end{document}
```

For the sake of portability, and this example, I've used [`filecontents`](http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents) to write `company_style.sty` as part of the minimal example.

Within `company_style.sty`, the `\title` macro is redefined to *always* include the company name - `Company XYZ` - and the company logo - `example-image` (or whatever you decide to use).

Comment: I tried something similar to your solution but my compiler complained that I was trying to insert an image outside of the main document flow. Anyway, your solution worked - Thanks!